# Merging of arrays containing duplicate elements using PRAM algorithm

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I am learning PRAM algorithms. I stuck at one question. "There exists an algorithm which,given any two sorted  m-element array of integers,where each integer belongs to the set{1,2,3...m} and where duplicate elements are allowed, merges the two arrays in O(1) time using PRAM with m common CRCW processors"

e.g.with m=4 ,it could merge the arrays<1,2,3,3>and<1,3,3,4> in O(1) time using 4 common CRCW processors

Please reply, 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

as soon as you have M processors, and M-length arrays and I don't see any mention that final array should be sorted:

each processor can take 1 value from 1st array and 1 value from 2nd array and put them into final array, and this operation will be O(1)

try to look into this pseudo-code:

```
int array1[M] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int array2[M] = {1, 3, 3, 4};
int output[M * 2] = {};

parallel for (i=0; i<M; i++) // each iteration of this loop runs on its own processor, so all iterations run at the same time and will finish in O(1) time simultaneously
{
    output[i * 2] = array1[i];
    output[i * 2 + 1] = array2[i];
}
```

so, operation in loop is obviously is O(1), and in general programming we can say that final complexity will be O(M), because of loop, but for M processors it will be only O(1)

Answer (score -1):

So we have M processors Concurrent Read, Concurrent Write and 2 arrays: a,b.
We can do this (kind of sorting by counting the appearences of each number):

```
//index     0  1  2  3  4  5
int a[M] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6};      
int b[M] = {1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 8};             
int o[M * 2] = {}; 
int tem1[M * 2] = {};  
int tem2[M * 2] = {};                     

parallel for (i=0; i<M; i++) 
// each iteration of this loop runs on its own processor, so all iterations run at the same 
// time and will finish in O(1) time simultaneously
// at reading/writing from/in the same location, processor i has higher priority than processor i+1, operations are queued
{
 // step 1 (depending on how much the values repeat, there will be processors that wait for others with higher priority,  // before performing their operations)
 tem1[a[i]]++;    
 tem2[b[i]]++;
 //   index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 // -> tem1: 0 4 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0  0  0
 // -> tem2: 0 1 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 0  0  0


 // step 2
 // again, some processors might wait until they perform their operations, because they access the same memory location
 o[tem1[a[i]+tem2[a[i]]-1] = a[i];
 tem1[a[i]]--;
 o[tem1[b[i]]+tem2[b[i]]-1] = b[i];
 tem2[b[i]]--;
 //   index: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 // ->    o: 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 6 8

}
```

-> no loops, constant number of operations for each processor -> O(1)

Comment: *depending on how much the values repeat, there will be processors that wait for others with higher priority* - it doesn't seem as constant time operation to me.